# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: errors

I get this error when I enter data in my form

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in

\functions.php on line 77

```
return '<span class="vwbx">Views</span>''<span class="vwbx">$count.</span>';
```

==== Whole function===

```
function getPostViews($postID){
$count_key = 'post_views_count';
$count = get_post_meta($postID, $count_key, true);
if($count==''){
    delete_post_meta($postID, $count_key);
    add_post_meta($postID, $count_key, '0');
    return "0 View";
}
return $count. '<span class="vwbx">Views</span>''<span class="vwbx">views</span>';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have two strings that aren't actually being appended together.

Try replacing

```
return $count. '<span class="vwbx">Views</span>''<span class="vwbx">views</span>';
```

With

```
return $count. '<span class="vwbx">Views</span>'.'<span class="vwbx">views</span>';
```

(note the added period in the centre).

Or instead, remove the two quotation marks from the centre:

```
return $count. '<span class="vwbx">Views</span><span class="vwbx">views</span>';
```

That should work :D

**EDIT**
In response to your comment... I think you'll be wanting to replace it with:

```
return '<span class="vwbx">Views</span><span class="bxarw"></span><span class="CntBx">'.$count.'</span>';
```

Comment: thanks Harris working
but i need to do this, to get $count value like 
return '<span class="vwbx">Views</span><span class="bxarw"></span><span class="CntBx">$count.</span>';

Comment: I've edited my answer :D. By the way, you may want to start accepting answers to your questions - your score is very low and people may decide not to bother answering you.